# What could be causing the copper green smells in my house when the furnace turns on?

Tags: cleaning, smell, copper, green

We just re-did the rotting siding on my t1-11 sided fireplace. We replaced siding and covered it with hardi-plank. The problem is, when my furnace turns on, air is pulled from the fire place and the whole living room smells like copper green. This was one week ago. Now I am very sick, can not go to work, have a doctors appointment tomorrow morning. I am wondering if this smell can be what is making me sick?, or is it a return on my colitis? I am weak, tired dizzy, headachey, and in much digestive distress. Any help or info would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: there is a lot going on here. Why is the furnace pulling air from your fireplace? What is the connection between hardi-plank and copper green?

Comment: Why is air pulled from the fireplace?  Do you mean for combustion or circulation?

Answer (score 1):

If by Copper-Green you mean any of the copper-naphthalene wood preservatives out there used to prevent wood rot, **and** it was applied to the studding, etc. that supports this fireplace shell:

**These products are not to be used within living spaces** or in construction where the fumes will be pulled into the living space.

Apply caulking to seal up the air gaps that allow air to get in from the external structure.

If any of it is inside the living space, it will need to be ripped out.

If no Copper Naphthalene products were used for wood preservation and rather it's the acrid creosote smell of air being drawn down the chimney despite the damper being closed, then you've got another problem altogether. Your secondary air intake for your furnace is plugged or you are missing one and the negative pressure in the living space is drawing air from wherever it can find ventilation.

**Note:** Hardi-Plank as produced by James Hardie is a cement board product that needs no preservatives to prevent rot.